# Consumir web service do PJe

Tags: java, web-service, api, rest, soap

Necessito consumir o andamento de um processo utilizando o web service providenciado pelo PJe. Estou seguindo as orientações descritas em:

http://www.pje.jus.br/wiki/index.php/Tutorial_MNI

De acordo com o tutorial, o WSDL possui o seguinte formato:

```
• Web Service: http://ENDEREÇO DA APLICAÇÃO DO PJe/intercomunicacao?wsdl
• Consultas complementares: http://ENDEREÇO DA APLICAÇÃO DO PJe/ConsultaPJe?wsdl
```

Entretanto, não encontrei o endereço da aplicação do PJe do TRT4 informado (nem mesmo em  http://www.pje.jus.br/wiki/index.php/Utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_do_PJe)

Já possuo acesso ao PJe de forma que precisaria apenas do WSDL correto para que eu possa testar a requisição com a ferramenta SOAP UI.

**Basicamente a pergunta é: qual o WSDL do TRT4 (ou melhor ainda, de qualquer TRT). Alternativamente, existe alguma API REST disponível para este propósito?**

*Nota: muitas aplicações fazem este tipo de serviço e criar um web crawler que resolva o CAPTCHA não é uma opção.*

*Nota 2: Existem múltiplas fontes para obter dados de tribunais, este link mostra diversas alternativas: https://www.digesto.com.br/cobertura*

Comment: Do que se trata essa aplicação PJe? É um arcabouço de *web services*? O TRT4 necessitaria se cadastrar para ficar disponível na listagem dos *web services*, você tem certeza que ele está cadastrado?

Comment: Sim, todos os TRTs utilizam a aplicação (exemplo: https://www.trt4.jus.br/portais/trt4/pje). Além disso, várias aplicações consomem esta API do TRT4 como por exemplo a Astrea e Digesto. Neste link http://www.pje.jus.br/wiki/index.php/Utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_do_PJe estão listadas WSDLs de vários tribunais, mas nenhum trabalhista. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Os TRTs utilizam um fork do PJe do CNJ. Acredito que o recurso de Web Services não esteja disponível.

Comment: Veja se [isso](http://www.pje.jus.br/wiki/index.php/Utiliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_do_PJe#Servi.C3.A7o_de_Interoperabilidade_.28MNI.29), ou [isso](http://www.cnj.jus.br/programas-e-acoes/pj-justica-em-numeros/selo-justica-em-numeros/orientacoes-para-envio-via-servico-rest) te ajuda.

Comment: Veja essa cartilha de integração disponibilizada pelo CNJ: [CIWS](http://www.cnj.jus.br/files/conteudo/arquivo/2016/08/04756e85a5af34413f9d6298a44f1ce4.pdf). Na página 7 tem o seguinte link: [URL](http://wwwh.cnj.jus.br/bnpr-web/bnprTSWS?wsdl)

Comment: Eu também estou precisando consumir os dados dos TRT via API rest, se alguém souber por favor compartilhar s2

Answer (score 1):

Olá, Rafael, O PJE foi desenvolvido pelo CNJ e cada instancia do PJE que é mantida pelos tribunais, sejam estaduais ou federais, seguem as determinações do CNJ. 
Dito isto, cada tribunal é responsável Manter o PJE de sua responsabilidade e por liberar o acesso ao WEBSERVICE que você deseja acessar, sugiro que você entre em contato com o tribunal desejado e solicite formalmente o acesso ao ambiente de testes para efetuar a conexao e iniciar os testes de integração com o MNI. 
O endereço para conhecer o MNI:

http://www.cnj.jus.br/biblioteca-cliente-do-mni/

Você pode utilizar um programa como o SOAP UI para criar os envelopes SOAP e fazer a conexao. Mas antes de qualquer coisa, mesmo para testes, você precisa ter permissão do Tribunal para consumir os servicos que estão descritos no WSDL. 
Geralmente o WSDL das instancias do PJE terminam com {URL}/intercomunicacao?wsdl